# MySQL fetch data processor stuck on second run

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi

I've got simple mysql GenerateTableFetch processor stuck infinitely on the second run. When I'm starting the flow - works like a charm, and on the next scheduled run it's stuck.

The flow: take data from remote mysql server from one table, make transformations and put it to sql server.

[image: Flow]

[image: Processor]

[image: Connection pool]

Mysql driver location: file:///home/user/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar

Nifi version 1.7.1.

What I tried:

different mysql connectors (5.1.47 and 8.0.12), different processors (QueryDatabaseTable, ExecuteSQL) - all stuck the same way.

Identical flow from sql server to sql server works perfect.

From dump log looks like thread stuck on trying to close previous mysql connection:

```
"Abandoned connection cleanup thread" Id=3080 TIMED_WAITING  on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@607800ac
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Number of Locked Synchronizers: 1
    - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1f01ec47
```

What could be the problem? Or what can I check next?

Thanks!

Comment: Try Increasing the Max wait time... 
And are you sure that there are no issues with your connections?(like poor connections and interruptions due to any reason)

Comment: I tried to increase max wait time, max total connections - doesn't help. For now I have another tool implementing this flow - works without a problem (but the tool is not flexible enough as nifi). Also if I stop and terminate the stuck processor and then rerun - it will work. It fails only on the second run.

Comment: And you sure it is not going to failure route?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I tried to add LogMessage on failure.

Comment: This processor manages state. When you say it's stuck, do you mean you have new data added to the table but still GenerateTableFetch doesn't detect it and generate a FlowFile ?

Comment: I can see there 1 active thread that does nothing and after half an hour it is terminated. There is nothing defined in max column attribute, so the query is not incremental - it takes almost the same data each time.